# How to set CATALINA_HOME in Windows 7 command line?

Tags: command-line, tomcat

After installing Tomcat on Windows 7, I would like to start Tomcat in the command line instead of using `tomcat7.exe` from the folder (Windows GUI). Tomcat is installed under `C:\opt\Tomcat7`.

Added Tomcat system variable, `CATALINA_HOME`, and `CATALINA_HOME` is set to `C:\opt\Tomcat7`. At the `C:\` command prompt, I am using `CATALINA_HOME\bin\startup.bat`, but  it is not recognizing `CATALINA_HOME`. If I type the full path, `C:\opt\Tomcat7\bin\startup.bat`,it works.

Is there anything that I have to do at the command line to set the Catalina environment?

Comment: Maybe you should add the directories to the PATH variable.

Comment: In case of `set "CATALINA_HOME=C:\opt\Tomcat7"` you could use `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat`

Comment: @JosefZ, it worked with %.   Problem resolved. thx all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of you have defined

```
set "CATALINA_HOME=C:\opt\Tomcat7"
```

you could use (in most contexts, surround the variable name with `%`s and the variable's *value* will be used):

```
 %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat
```

Note:

- `SET` [Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html). Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- `SETX.EXE` [Set environment variables permanently](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html): `SETX` *can* be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (`HKLM`) or currently logged on user (`HKCU`).